# Bootstrap swiped scrollable tabs like in Google Play

Tags: javascript, cordova

Is there any package or plugin to create swipeable tabs like in Google Play?

I'm creating a cordova application using angularjs and bootstrap..

Comment: something like this? http://www.material-ui.com/#/

Comment: Looks like yes, material-ui tabs + "react-swipeable-views" works great as i see on these examples.. But will it work with angular js and bootstrap?

Comment: It should be broken down in components and you should be able to use only what you need. As for angular, material-ui is a CSS framework, you should find angular packages which implement it (e.g. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/). Or you can simply use the CSS as is and build your own components